# Kubernetes - How to show all service accounts

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, gcp

How do I show all service accounts In Kubernetes?

I have tried `kubectl get --all-namespaces all`. It does not show service accounts.

How can I use `kubectl` to list all service accounts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The command you listed will show you your resources.

Instead try: `kubectl get serviceAccounts`

Comment: Is there a way to get everything? I actually want to see resources, service accounts, cluster role bindings, everything. I am trying to clean up my nodes and would appreciate a way to get a birds eye view.

Comment: Are you trying to get all the information tied to that service account?  If so check out the official docs here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/.  Otherwise you may want to look into https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/ for a dashboard or chain commands together (e.g. kubectl get --all-namespaces && kubectl get serviceAccounts)

Comment: Popeye helps... https://github.com/derailed/popeye

Comment: if your `serviceAccount` is not in your current `namespace` you should use `-A` for looking on all your `namespaces` or target an specific one with `-n=foobar` if you know in which `namespace` is your resource.

Answer (score 9):

kubectl get sa --all-namespaces

This will only provide the service accounts.

In general, you can have a comma separated list of resources to display.

Example:

kubectl get pods,svc,sa,deployments [-FLAGS]

The FLAGS would apply to all the resources.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, and worked for me. Thanks!